# How do I deal with a list threshold error?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am writing the below script for SharePoint online and have been running into an error regarding list thresholds.
I am trying to find the amount of files in a certain document library, and eventually I would like to write code that allows me to remove specific permissions from the different sites.
Is this something I can fix in this code?

```
$fullSite = "https://website.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename"
$list = "name"

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $fullSite -UseWebLogin 

$listItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $list 

    $count = 0
    foreach($listItem in $listItems){
        $count = $count + 1
        }
    Write-Output $count
```

Comment: there are different types of thresholds. Could you give the specific error message? get-pnplistitem should take care of the 5000 item threshold by default. Perhaps there are too many lookup/person fields in the result set?

Answer (score 0):

Check if this gets you the item count

```
$fullSite = "https://website.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename"
$list = "name"  #display name
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $fullSite -UseWebLogin
$list = Get-PnPList -Identity $($list)
$count = $list.ItemCount
```

Comment: I used this code: 

`Connect-PnPOnline -Url $fullSite -UseWebLogin
$list = Get-PnPList
$count = $list.ItemCount
Write-Output $count`

And got this result:
1
2
3
0
0
0
2905
18
0
566
3
7876
7833
0
468
0
1
16765
175
32801
9
106
4
49
13
3
0
0
0
1
240
57993
540
51
1891
23

Comment: Try the updated code. You can also try putting guid of list instead of name.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSOM to get items by pagination.

Sample Script:

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

#region Variables 
$Username = "user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com" 
$Password = "password" 
$siteURL = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/lee" 
#endregion Variables

#region Credentials 
[SecureString]$SecurePass = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force 
$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Username, $SecurePass) 
#endregion Credentials

#Parameters
$ListName="MyList"
$BatchSize="5"

Try {    
    #Setup the context
    $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
    $Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials

    #Get the List
    $List = $Ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListName)
    $Ctx.Load($List)
    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

    #Define Query to get List Items in batch
    $Query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
    $Query.ViewXml = @"
    <View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
        <Query>
            <OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='TRUE'/></OrderBy>
        </Query>
        <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">$BatchSize</RowLimit>
    </View>
"@

    #Get List Items in Batch
    Do
    {
        $ListItems = $List.GetItems($Query)
        $Ctx.Load($ListItems)
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
        $ListItems.count
        $Query.ListItemCollectionPosition = $ListItems.ListItemCollectionPosition
    }
    While($Query.ListItemCollectionPosition -ne $null)

}
Catch {
    write-host -f Red "Error Getting List Items:" $_.Exception.Message
}
```